# aeond connection problems

Tags: aeon, error-log, daemon

When starting the current version of `aeond` (aeon v0.9.12.0) I get tbe following message:

```
Starting...
aeon v0.9.12.0()
Module folder: ./aeond
Initializing p2p server...
Binding on 0.0.0.0:11180
ERROR /aeon/contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:468 Exception at [boosted_tcp_server<t_protocol_handler>::init_server], what=bind: Address already in use
ERROR /aeon/src/p2p/net_node.inl:300 Failed to bind server
ERROR /aeon/src/daemon/daemon.cpp:175 Failed to initialize p2p server.
```

How can I fix the above error and connect to the network?

Comment: Don't you have a daemon already running on your computer?

Comment: I can reproduce your error message by attempting running **two** instances of aeond on the same computer. As @clement-j suggests, it's the second aeond that causes the error — the first aeond just keeps on rollin’ along like Ol’ Man River.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As predicted by Clement and TEV in question comments, it turns out I already had another daemon running in the background that I was not aware of. The issue disappeared once I restarted my system and ran `aeond` again